# Python - Dynamic replacement of long field with short code from another file

Tags: python, csv, dynamic, replace

I have a csv stock list file that I receive regularly throughout the day that contains a number of fields per item.  These fields include, among other details, a Manufacturers Product Number (MPN), the full manufacturers name as well as the latest stock count.  I also have a separate file, which is stored in a different folder, where I hold a record of each manufacturer and a short code (2 characters) I have assigned to them (AT for Airthings, RG for Ring, etc).

I have cobbled together the below working script (by surfing these forums) which takes the original stock file and creates a new file that appends a new field to each record - currently representing the concatenation of some fixed text ("ST-") plus the manufacturers full name (column 5 of the csv) plus some more fixed text ("-") plus the MPN (column 1 of the csv).

I would, though, like to replace the manufacturers full name in this string to be the two character code I have associated with the manufacturer in the separate file.  Is this possible?  How could I amend the below script to do this?

Many Thanks.

S

```
 import csv

 with open('C:/Stores/stockfeed/Stockfeedi.csv','r') as csvinput:
 with open('C:/Stores/stockfeed/Stockfeedo.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append('SKU')
    all.append(row)

    for row in reader:
        row.append("ST-" + row[4] + "-" + row[0])  #This is the line I need help with
        all.append(row)

    writer.writerows(all)
```

example of stockfeedi.csv

MPN, Display Name/Code, UPC Code, Price, Brand, Bin On Hand Available, Available, Stock Category
"SHA5209","ENER-J OUTDOOR TWIN PIR FLOODLIGHT BLACK","7103356056844","60.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation"
"BW1001","ENER-J INSTANT HOT WATER TAP","7103351516954","60.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation"
"Y28 EU","Kami Mini Fixed Indoor Camera EU","6970171176443","34.37","Kami","0","Unknown","Video Capture "
"ENER010","Energenie - 4 Gang RF Extension","5060166030117","21.24","Energenie","37","Available","Energenie"
"SHA5204","Smart WiFi 1 Gang Touch Switch","7061252103720","11.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation"
"CostcoPOS9","Ring Alarm Pallet POS","0000000000108",".00","RING","0","Unknown","RING"
"CostcoPOS10","Ring Stick Up Cam Battery White Duo Pack Pallet POS","0000000000109",".00","RING","0","Unknown","RING"
"L83","Lightwave Smart Relay (3 Gang)","5060252202862","99.13","Lightwave","63","Available","Home Automation"
"AIRTCH","Airthings Corentium Home","7090031102227","92.75","Airthings","47","Available","Home Automation"
"MIHO099","Mi Home - Smart Thermostat with Gateway","5060166038557","92.08","Energenie","1","Available","Energenie"
"L2","Lightwave Link Plus","5060252202558","92.05","Lightwave","26","Available","Home Automation"

example of stockfeedo.csv (produced by above script)

"MPN"," Display Name/Code"," UPC Code"," Price"," Brand"," Bin On Hand Available"," Available"," Stock Category","SKU"
"SHA5209","ENER-J OUTDOOR TWIN PIR FLOODLIGHT BLACK","7103356056844","60.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation","TD-Ener-J-SHA5209"
"BW1001","ENER-J INSTANT HOT WATER TAP","7103351516954","60.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation","TD-Ener-J-BW1001"
"Y28 EU","Kami Mini Fixed Indoor Camera EU","6970171176443","34.37","Kami","0","Unknown","Video Capture ","TD-Kami-Y28 EU"
"ENER010","Energenie - 4 Gang RF Extension","5060166030117","21.24","Energenie","37","Available","Energenie","TD-Energenie-ENER010"
"SHA5204","Smart WiFi 1 Gang Touch Switch","7061252103720","11.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation","TD-Ener-J-SHA5204"
"CostcoPOS9","Ring Alarm Pallet POS","0000000000108",".00","RING","0","Unknown","RING","TD-RING-CostcoPOS9"
"CostcoPOS10","Ring Stick Up Cam Battery White Duo Pack Pallet POS","0000000000109",".00","RING","0","Unknown","RING","TD-RING-CostcoPOS10"
"L83","Lightwave Smart Relay (3 Gang)","5060252202862","99.13","Lightwave","63","Available","Home Automation","TD-Lightwave-L83"
"AIRTCH","Airthings Corentium Home","7090031102227","92.75","Airthings","47","Available","Home Automation","TD-Airthings-AIRTCH"
"MIHO099","Mi Home - Smart Thermostat with Gateway","5060166038557","92.08","Energenie","1","Available","Energenie","TD-Energenie-MIHO099"
"L2","Lightwave Link Plus","5060252202558","92.05","Lightwave","26","Available","Home Automation","TD-Lightwave-L2"

example of separate code csv file

Manufacturer,Code
Ener-J,EJ
Kami,KM
Energenie,EG
RING,RG
Lightwave,LW
Airthings,AT
LIFX,LF

example of how I'd like stockfeedo.csv to be

"MPN"," Display Name/Code"," UPC Code"," Price"," Brand"," Bin On Hand Available"," Available"," Stock Category","SKU"
"SHA5209","ENER-J OUTDOOR TWIN PIR FLOODLIGHT BLACK","7103356056844","60.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation","TD-EJ-SHA5209"
"BW1001","ENER-J INSTANT HOT WATER TAP","7103351516954","60.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation","TD-EJ-BW1001"
"Y28 EU","Kami Mini Fixed Indoor Camera EU","6970171176443","34.37","Kami","0","Unknown","Video Capture ","TD-KM-Y28 EU"
"ENER010","Energenie - 4 Gang RF Extension","5060166030117","21.24","Energenie","37","Available","Energenie","TD-EJ-ENER010"
"SHA5204","Smart WiFi 1 Gang Touch Switch","7061252103720","11.00","Ener-J","0","Unknown","Home Automation","TD-EJ-SHA5204"
"CostcoPOS9","Ring Alarm Pallet POS","0000000000108",".00","RING","0","Unknown","RING","TD-RG-CostcoPOS9"
"CostcoPOS10","Ring Stick Up Cam Battery White Duo Pack Pallet POS","0000000000109",".00","RING","0","Unknown","RING","TD-RG-CostcoPOS10"
"L83","Lightwave Smart Relay (3 Gang)","5060252202862","99.13","Lightwave","63","Available","Home Automation","TD-LW-L83"
"AIRTCH","Airthings Corentium Home","7090031102227","92.75","Airthings","47","Available","Home Automation","TD-AT-AIRTCH"
"MIHO099","Mi Home - Smart Thermostat with Gateway","5060166038557","92.08","Energenie","1","Available","EJ","TD-Energenie-MIHO099"
"L2","Lightwave Link Plus","5060252202558","92.05","Lightwave","26","Available","Home Automation","TD-LW-L2"

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the files? I have a solution, just want to make sure it will work with what you have.

Comment: Hi @SimonEvans, your question is too detailed for us to read and spend time to understand. Would you care to give a short MWE so that we can help you with your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to read your main data file into a Pandas DataFrame, read the reference file into a dictionary, and call the `.replace()` method on the Manufacturer column of the DataFrame, passing the dict as an argument. This will look for the dict's keys in the column and replace them with the corresponding value from the dict. This works granted that there are matching items in both files, i.e. in the stock list you have the Manufacturer's name, and that same name appears somewhere in the reference file.